# error del localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin

Soy nuevo en php y mysql y no estoy entendiendo el error

Se ha encontrado un error PHP
Gravedad: Advertencia

Mensaje: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Acceso denegado para el usuario 'root'''localhost' (usando la contraseña: YES)

Nombre de archivo: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Número de línea: 201

Backtrace:

Archivo: C:-xampp-htdocs-stock-application-core-MY_Controller.php
Línea: 7
Función: __construct

Archivo: C:-xampp-htdocs-stock-application-core-MY_Controller.php
Línea: 17
Función: __construct

Archivo: C:-xampp-htdocs-stock-application-controllers-Auth.php
Línea:
10 Función: __construct

Archivo: C:-xampp-htdocs-stock-index.php
Línea: 315
Función: require_once

Comment: En resumen, te ha denegado el acceso, el problema te salta en mysqli_driver en la linea 201

Comment: Parece que estás poniendo como nombre de usuario `'root'''localhost'`... Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código de tu archivo de conexión a la BD (cambia los datos sensibles reales por `****` u otros ficticios).